# Wildcard tag results in "or or or ..."

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, new-nav

When accessing the wildcard tag [`[boost*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost*), a lot of boost tags are listed as well as multiple "or or or ..." as shown on this screenshot:

[image]

what is the reason for this?
is it a bug?

This also happens for other tags such as [`[c++*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++*)

Comment: I suspect it *should* read something like "[tag:boost] or [tag:boost-asio] or [tag:boost-bind] or [tag:boost-filesystem] or ..." No idea why or how it's broken like that, though. (FWIW, my original guess was wrong: it's not a CSS issue, the "or"s really are placed like that in the DOM too.)

Comment: I can't see, where is it?

Comment: @klenium what can't you see?

Comment: @m.s. What you shown in the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/d1yOtP5.png

Comment: @klenium interesting, it is shown for me above the questions: http://i.imgur.com/5HvjJu3.png

Comment: @klenium It's the new navigation UI. You have to opt-in for beta-testing.

Comment: @MCMastery don't you think the "or"s should be placed in between the tags?

Comment: @m.s. Yes (I was joking!).

Comment: They just *really* like seals.

Comment: For [\[oracle*\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle*) the stream of "or"s come before the actual tags, so seems to be an alphabetic component. They also appear in the expanded URL.

Comment: i have the same issue in an old bookmark, simply remove the or from the search text and bookmark again

Comment: @Matteo this is not related to a bookmark, click on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++*) and you'll see

Comment: no problems for me on Opera 30.0.1835.125

Comment: @SpaceTrucker have you enabled the new navigation UI?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300282/3488231 . Also, it seems that this is already reported on meta.se: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261513/259700

Comment: ewww somebody doesn't know how to use float

Comment: @m.s. No, I haven't. I didn't notice the tag, but only read the question content.

Comment: Working on it...

Comment: @MarcGravell the "or"s are gone from the tag list but are still in the title of the page, see http://i.imgur.com/qVtnjHO.png

Answer (score 2):

The current release supports boolean tag searches.