# URL with several tags joined by OR is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, new-nav

Until recently I have been successfully using this URL to monitor new questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+or+asp.net-mvc+or+asp.net-mvc-2+or+asp.net-mvc-3+or+asp.net-mvc-4+or+asp.net-mvc-5+or+linq+or+perl+or+razor+or+c%23

However now it seems to be broken. Navigating to the link above results in this:

[image: interface or bug]

And the only filter applied is by last tag in the chain.

Simpler link with the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+or+css

And the very same thing happens if you enter `[html] or [css]` in the search text box, which is a [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) way of "or" searching.

Comment: To force the old search, use `is:q`.

Comment: @Martijn: Even if the change in search behavior is [meta-tag:status-bydesign], the breakage of old links and bookmarks is surely a bug. There should be a graceful fallback of some kind (like, say, just stripping "or" from the list of tags).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: I'd say conversion of old-style URLs to the new system is a [tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Martijn: Do you really think I need to file a *feature request* for "URLs that used to work shouldn't suddenly stop working for no good reason"? I would think that should already *be* a feature of any halfway decently designed web site, except of course when unintentional errors (i.e. bugs) happen, in which case they should be fixed when noticed. Remember, [Cool URIs don't change.](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: This whole thing is in *alpha release*, it is an as-yet incomplete preview for a wider audience. At this point in time conversion of old URLs is a feature request.

Comment: @Martijn: Clearly we have a different understanding of what "bug" and "feature request" mean; I've never heard of this distinction depending on the stage we're at in the release cycle. Sure, a bug found during alpha might be [meta-tag:status-deferred] to a later stage, but it's still a bug. But enough of the semantics -- what I'm really trying to say here is that I'm at least 99% sure that the real issue being reported here, i.e. the *breakage of old URLs*, is *not* [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. Nobody sat down and thought "Hey, let's break all these old links! It'll be fun!"

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: sometimes these lines are blurred. No, breaking old URLs is not by design. What is by design is that the new system no longer needs explicit `or`s in the URL because the new system allows you to switch between the two styles with a UI element.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300270/3488231

Comment: Sometimes [it's both a bug and a feature request](http://blog.codinghorror.com/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request/).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You no longer need to use `[or]` or `or` in your tag searches, the new UI lets you toggle between searching for posts with any or all of the tags.

Just remove those from the link; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html+css works, it'll redirect to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=css%20html&mode=any`. Note the `mode=any` in that URL. Use the `any / all` switch in the UI to switch between search modes.

Your longer URL becomes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net+asp.net-mvc+asp.net-mvc-2+asp.net-mvc-3+asp.net-mvc-4+asp.net-mvc-5+linq+perl+or+razor+c%23 and redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&tags=asp.net%20asp.net-mvc%20asp.net-mvc-2%20asp.net-mvc-3%20asp.net-mvc-4%20asp.net-mvc-5%20c%23%20linq%20or%20perl%20razor&mode=any

Comment: Indeed, thanks for sharing. Perhaps the help page should be updated though.

Comment: @Andrei: the new feature is still in alpha testing. I'm sure the help pages will be updated when the feature is actually going to be enabled for everyone.

Comment: And how would one do a search like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+java+or+c%23+php ?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I guess that such searches are no longer supported with the new UI.

Comment: That's ... unfortunate.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I suggest opening separate tabs for `java javascript` and `c# php`.

Comment: Well, when it's a query I actually do, the results from either part normally have *significant* overlap. So that's not really a practical thing to do...

Comment: It doesn't do the `mode` redirect for me.

Comment: Similar but not quite same issue with wildcard tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell*  Example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261513/419