# How can I exclude tags from new search?

Tags: support, search, new-nav

The exclusion of tags when searching no longer works directly, similarly to [disjunction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300282/url-with-several-tags-joined-by-or-is-broken). A [comment suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300282/url-with-several-tags-joined-by-or-is-broken#comment-226511) this is might be only a question of translation.

So how can I search for a tag and exclude another tag?

(Just as a general remark, the new design causes me to at least subjectively land more on unneeded pages where I have to adjust the search settings which is rather painful with mobile connections)

Comment: MSE duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259915/280467 but basically add another search restriction like is:q

Answer (score 1):

Add `is:` at the end of the question, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[iso-prolog]+-[prolog]+is%3A).